# Max and min of functions in order-notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Order notation question, big-o notation and the like:

**What does the max and min of a function mean in terms of order notation?**

for example:

> **DEFINITION:**
>
> "Maximum" rules: Suppose that f(n) and g(n) are positive functions for all n > n<sub>0</sub>.
>
> > Then:
> >
> > > - O[f(n) + g(n)] = O[max (f(n),g(n)) ]
> > > - etc...

I need to use these definitions to prove something for homework.. thanks for the help!

EDIT: f(n) and g(n) are supposed to represent running times of algorithms with respect to input size

Comment: I think you will get more responses (and it will be more suitable for) at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Zenzen: cstheory is for research level questions. This question is not research level, and thus is off topic for cstheory.

Comment: @Zenzen: A bit below their pay-grade really.

Comment: haha.. sorry for asking a question that might not be exactly a programming question - i'm kinda desperate for an answer and was hoping somebody in here would be familiar with my undergrad shenanigans :)

Comment: Oh, it's definitely a programming question. How are you supposed to know whether you're using a sensible algorithm if you can't work out its complexity? To do _that_, you need this stuff. (This is the rule for combining the complexities of things in sequence.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Big-O notation, you're talking about upper bounds on computation. This means that you are only interested in the *largest* term of the combined function as *n* (the variable) tends to infinity. What's more, you drop any constant multipliers as well since the formal definition of the notation allows you to discard those parts, which is important as it allows you to focus on the algorithm's behavior and not on the implementation of the algorithm.

So, we are combining two functions through summation. Well, there are two cases (strictly three, but it's symmetric):

1. One function is of higher order than the other. At that point, the higher order function dominates the lesser; you can pretend that the lesser doesn't exist.
2. Both functions are of the same order. This is just like you are doing some kind of ratio-ed sum of the two (since we've already thrown away the scaling factors) but then you just end up with the same factor and have just changed the scaling factors a bit.

The net result looks very much like the max() function, even though it's really not (it's actually a generalization of max over the space of functions), so it's very convenient to use the notation.

Comment: to clarify, max(f(n),g(n)) is the max of the two functions as you take  n->infinity? what if, for example, f(2) < g(2) but f(100000) > g(100000)? or is the max function completely dependent on n?

Comment: Since it's inside a big-O, it is indeed as things tend to infinity. However, it's important to remember that when working with big-O you don't talk about specific values (if you want those, just measure the code with a performance analysis framework!) but instead work analytically with the functions themselves. Thus, f(n) will always be a pretty simple function in n, typically using a single polynomial term together with zero or more log components.

Comment: Log is important in complexity analysis because it's characteristic of divide-and-conquer algorithms, which are often very efficient. It's regarded as being larger than constant (i.e., it does tend to infinity) yet smaller than any non-constant polynomial term (it tends to infinity _slowly_).

Answer (score 3):

It is a regular max between natural numbers. `f` is a function mapped to numbers [`f:N->N`], and so is `g`.

Thus, `f(n)` is in `N`, and so `max(f(n),g(n))` is just standard max: `f(n) > g(n) ? f(n) : g(n)`

`O[max (f(n),g(n)) ]` means: which ever is more 'expensive': `f` or `g`: it is the upper bound.

Comment: are you saying that max(f(n),g(n)) is just whichever is larger as n->infinity? so its sort of like the max of the limits of f(n) and g(n)?

Comment: @IrWin: no, note that it is a different function, let it be `h`, such that `h(n) = max(f(n),g(n))`, `h` could have a different value for `n` for value of `n`. a trivial example would be: `max(n,n^2) = n^2` because for each `n`: `n^2 >= n`, and thus `O(max(n,n^2)) = O(n^2)`